# Is there a name for riddles that use two languages - such that only people who know both languages would understand them?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, solicitud-de-término

Is there a name for riddles that use two languages - such that only people who know both languages would understand them?

As an example/Por ejemplo:

**Question/Pregunta**: What do you call a hog that is always asking questions?

**Answer/Respuesta**: Por que Pig

In other words, you have to know at least a little of both languages to "get" the answer - is there "such a thing"?

Comment: I know another. A little skunk (zorrillo in Spanish) gets lost at the zoo and gets to the jaguar's cage. The jaguars ask the skunk "How are you (Jaguar you)?" and the skunk answers "No, I'm **z**orry". More a joke than a riddle, but again you need to know both languages to make some sense of it.

Comment: All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a *reverse dictionary* where you can try to search a word given its definition: [DIRAE](http://dirae.es/). I have tried to search your proposal, but no results were found. In fact, I have never heard of something like that, so I would go for something like *adivinanza bilingüe* (*bilingual riddle*).